# Filter array of objects by array of filters

Tags: reactjs

so I am trying to apply some filters on array of objects. For example, I have two objects:

```
[
    {_id: "5e8e07f1b874fd27906b2f6a", index: "00004000003", manufacturer: "ABS", plasticType: "new16", color: "Red", …},
    {_id: "5e90e60c1485d58d88f0af6f", index: "00003000004", manufacturer: "ABS", plasticType: "new15", color: "Red", …}
]
```

And I have filters that apply to manufacturer, plasticType and color. So, if I want to see only objects whose manufacturer is `ABS`, plasticType is `new16` and color is `Red`, I need to apply some filters.

How could I do this?

Expected result should return only the first object.

I have tried this, but, clearly, it only returns the right result if all the conditions match.

```
data.filter((spool) =>
    filters.manufacturers.includes(spool.manufacturer) &&
    filters.plasticTypes.includes(spool.plasticType) &&
    filters.colors.includes(spool.color)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it by:

```
const filteredData = data.filter(el => el.manufacturer.includes("ABS") && 
      el.plasticType.includes('new16') && el.color.includes('Red'))
```

or

```
const filteredData = data.filter(el => el.manufacturer == "ABS" && el.plasticType == 
    'new16' && el.color == 'Red')
```

Comment: But this filters the objects that meet all of the requirements. For example, if I specify manufacturer as ABS and plasticType as new16, but leave the color blank, I wouldn't get any results.

Comment: Just delete the condition you dont need in this case, remove the `el.color == 'Red'`